# What is the name for the axis that "inclination angle" is measured from in spherical coordinates?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

What is the name for the axis that "inclination angle" is measured from in spherical coordinates?

I keep trying to call it "polar axis", and the other axis from which the azimuth is measured, the "azimuthal axis".  Is this correct?

Comment: By "elevation", I meant the axis from which the "polar angle" is measured.  On the wiki, they call this the "inclination angle"!  Sorry, I actually had a mistake in the question!

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Even if some reference asserts the existence of a standard name for this axis, I would not use any term expecting people to know what it is. I assure you, the *vast* majority of people know of no standard name for that axis (except maybe "the $z$-axis"?). There is also no universal convention about which of the angles in spherical coordinates is called $\theta$ and which is $\varphi$ (and hence which angle is the "azimuthal angle"). Mathematicians tend to prefer $\theta$ to be the angle that is most analogous to the $\theta$ in 2D polar coordinates; many physicists use the opposite convention.

Comment: It would be easier to respond if you could tell us which variable precisely using [this diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) as reference.

Comment: I prefer calling the angles "longitude" and "co-latitude" myself, at least in the spherical coordinate system I am accustomed to. And finally, I don't know of any better term than "$z$-axis", as with Leslie...

Comment: To me, inclination is $\frac \pi 2-\theta$, that is, it is measured from the $xy$ plane and has a range of $[-90^{\circ },90^\circ ]$ as the people who use "inclination" also measure in degrees